# Statement parsing bug in flyway?

Tags: flyway

I've encountered a very strange error using flyway.  First, here is a version of my update script that works. (This is in a file named V57.3__foo.sql):

```sql
use database
go
set nocount on

create table userz (
username char(30),
firstname char(30),
lastname char(30),
activeind char(1)
)

insert into userz (username, firstname, lastname, activeind) Values('jsmith', 'John', 'Smith','a')


declare @username varchar(30),
        @firstname varchar(255),
        @lastname varchar(255),
        @activeind char(1)

DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT username, firstname, lastname, activeind FROM userz
OPEN the_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN

    declare @email varchar(255)
    SELECT @email=replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com'
    SELECT @email=lower(@email)
--    SELECT @email=lower(replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com')

    declare @deleted bit
    SELECT @deleted= case when @activeind='a' then 0 else 1 end

    FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
END

CLOSE the_cursor
DEALLOCATE the_cursor

drop table userz

set nocount off
go
```

When I turn on the application, I get this output:

```sql
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory - Database: Microsoft SQL Server 10.50
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway - DDL Transactions Supported: true
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway - Schema: dbo
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbSchemas - Schema [dbo] already exists. Skipping schema creation.
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableTo20FormatUpgrader - No upgrade to the Flyway 2.0 format necessary for metadata table [dbo].[schema_version]
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableTo202FormatUpgrader - No metadata table upgrade to the Flyway 2.0.2 format necessary
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableTo21FormatUpgrader - No metadata table upgrade to the Flyway 2.1 format necessary
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.Table - Locking table [dbo].[schema_version]...
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.Table - Lock acquired for table [dbo].[schema_version]
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.FeatureDetector - Spring Jdbc available: true
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning for classpath resources at 'db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning URL: file:/home/mcurwen/projects/core/target/classes/db/migration
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.FeatureDetector - JBoss VFS v2 available: false

---- very large snip of scanning/filtering ----

[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] INFO localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema [dbo]: 57.2
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] WARN localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema [dbo] may not be reproducible.
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] INFO localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Migrating schema [dbo] to version 57.3
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Found statement at line 1: use database

[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Found statement at line 3: set nocount on

create table userz (
username char(30),
firstname char(30),
lastname char(30),
activeind char(1)
)

insert into userz (username, firstname, lastname, activeind) Values('jsmith', 'John', 'Smith','a')


declare @username varchar(30),
        @firstname varchar(255),
        @lastname varchar(255),
        @activeind char(1)

DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT username, firstname, lastname, activeind FROM userz
OPEN the_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN

    declare @email varchar(255)
    SELECT @email=replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com'
    SELECT @email=lower(@email)
--    SELECT @email=lower(replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com')

    declare @deleted bit
    SELECT @deleted= case when @activeind='a' then 0 else 1 end

    FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
END

CLOSE the_cursor
DEALLOCATE the_cursor

drop table userz

set nocount off

[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Executing SQL: use database

[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Executing SQL: set nocount on

create table userz (
username char(30),
firstname char(30),
lastname char(30),
activeind char(1)
)

insert into userz (username, firstname, lastname, activeind) Values('jsmith', 'John', 'Smith','a')


declare @username varchar(30),
        @firstname varchar(255),
        @lastname varchar(255),
        @activeind char(1)

DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT username, firstname, lastname, activeind FROM userz
OPEN the_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN

    declare @email varchar(255)
    SELECT @email=replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com'
    SELECT @email=lower(@email)
--    SELECT @email=lower(replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com')

    declare @deleted bit
    SELECT @deleted= case when @activeind='a' then 0 else 1 end

    FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
END

CLOSE the_cursor
DEALLOCATE the_cursor

drop table userz

set nocount off

[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Successfully completed and committed migration of schema [dbo] to version 57.3
[2013-07-08 14:37:31] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Finished migrating schema [dbo] to version 57.3 (execution time 00:00.060s)
[2013-07-08 14:37:32] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl - MetaData table [dbo].[schema_version] successfully updated to reflect changes
```

As you see, it correctly identifies and then executes both statements.

But, if I comment out the two SELECT @email statements, and uncomment the third one, I get this output, and a failed migration. It only identifies one statement (according to its own logging) but then runs two statements anyway - the second one didn't trim the 'go' from the bottom.  again, the *only* change between the two is the SELECT statements being used in the cursor loop.

```sql
[2013-07-08 14:41:54] [] INFO localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Migrating schema [dbo] to version 57.3
[2013-07-08 14:41:54] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Found statement at line 1: use database

[2013-07-08 14:41:54] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Executing SQL: use database

[2013-07-08 14:41:54] [] DEBUG localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Executing SQL: set nocount on

create table userz (
username char(30),
firstname char(30),
lastname char(30),
activeind char(1)
)

insert into userz (username, firstname, lastname, activeind) Values('jsmith', 'John', 'Smith','a')


declare @username varchar(30),
        @firstname varchar(255),
        @lastname varchar(255),
        @activeind char(1)

DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT username, firstname, lastname, activeind FROM userz
OPEN the_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN

    declare @email varchar(255)
--    SELECT @email=replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com'
--    SELECT @email=lower(@email)
    SELECT @email=lower(replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com')

    declare @deleted bit
    SELECT @deleted= case when @activeind='a' then 0 else 1 end

    FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
END

CLOSE the_cursor
DEALLOCATE the_cursor

drop table userz

set nocount off
go
[2013-07-08 14:41:54] [] ERROR localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 3: set nocount on

create table userz (
username char(30),
firstname char(30),
lastname char(30),
activeind char(1)
)

insert into userz (username, firstname, lastname, activeind) Values('jsmith', 'John', 'Smith','a')


declare @username varchar(30),
        @firstname varchar(255),
        @lastname varchar(255),
        @activeind char(1)

DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT username, firstname, lastname, activeind FROM userz
OPEN the_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN

    declare @email varchar(255)
--    SELECT @email=replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com'
--    SELECT @email=lower(@email)
    SELECT @email=lower(replace(coalesce(@firstname, 'xxxxx')+'.'+coalesce(@lastname, 'xxxxx'),' ','')+'@domain.com')

    declare @deleted bit
    SELECT @deleted= case when @activeind='a' then 0 else 1 end

    FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @username, @firstname, @lastname, @activeind
END

CLOSE the_cursor
DEALLOCATE the_cursor

drop table userz

set nocount off
go
[2013-07-08 14:41:54] [] ERROR localhost-startStop-1  com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Caused by java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'go'.
[2013-07-08 14:41:54] [] ERROR localhost-startStop-1  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
```

And yes, my real migration does actually do something inside the loop - it calls a stored procedure to insert the new user.  This is demo code I made in the hopes that anyone could run and reproduce.

Comment: I've just noticed the pre tags ate the "not equals" <> in the above SQL statement while loops. They're actually there.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer your question but indent the code by 4 spaces (or highlight it and click the `{}` button) instead of using `<pre>` or `<code>` tags to avoid code such as `<>` being hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug indeed. My suspicion is that https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/543 might be biting you.

Adding a space before and after the + should do the trick. This one case is fixed in master. Please file an issue if the problem persists after the workaround.